# WPF Editable ComboBox

Tags: wpf

I have a ComboBox and ComboBox.IsEditable property is set to True to have a ComboBox act as both a TextBox and a drop-down list simultaneously.  But when the ComboBox is data-bound, entering custom text will not cause a new item to be added to the data-bound collection.

For example, if I enter 'Joe' in a ComboBox that is bound to a list of people, which doesn't contain the value 'Joe', then the value 'Joe' is not going to be added to the drop-down list automatically.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 94):

Here's a basic `MVVM` compliant way of getting the behaviour you want:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Margin="30,5,30,5"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                  Text="{Binding NewItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <TextBox Margin="30,5,30,5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _selectedItem;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
        "Five",
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public IEnumerable Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public string NewItem
    {
        set
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _items.Add(value);
                SelectedItem = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I had to place another control in the window as I have set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the `Text` binding to `LostFocus`. If there are no other controls in the window then the `Combobox` will never lose focus.

I changed the update mode because the default update mode is `Propertychanged` which will add a new item for each keystroke.

E.G. if you entered the text "Window", the following would be added to your collection:

```
W
Wi
Win
Wind
Windo
Window
```

Comment: I had to add a get { return SelectedItem; } to the NewItem property for me to work.

Comment: I tried this method, and it works but not always. There is Binding on the SelectedItem and on the Text property and it is uncertain which one fires first. It seems if the Text binding fires first then everything is ok, but if the Selected Item then it changes back the text.

Answer (score 11):

I would handle it in the LostFocus event.

Here you can check if the SelectedItem is null. If so, add the value of Text to the bound list and set SelectedItem to the new item.

In XAML:

```
  <ComboBox Name="_list" LostFocus="LostFocus" IsEditable="True"/>
```

In code-behind:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _names;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _names = new ObservableCollection<string> {"Eric", "Phillip"};
        _list.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding {Source = _names});
    }

    private void LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
        if(comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
            return;
        var newItem = comboBox.Text;
        _names.Add(newItem);
        comboBox.SelectedItem = newItem;
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You might also want to do it in the DropDownOpened event.

Comment: You should also handle PreviewKeyDown and process Key.Enter

Comment: I tried this solution but I had to use a SelectedItem Binding also. This caused a problem, it is uncertain if the SelectedItem binding will run first or the LostFocus. If the LostFocus then it is ok, if the SelectedItem then it will reset the text I just written into the ComboBox.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be using an MVVM-approach and bind your ComboBox.Text to some TextProperty of your ViewModel. (Same can be achieved by just adding a string property to your view)
Then you can treat the input in the setter of this property and add that new item to the list, no matter which way it was "committed" in the view.
AFAIK there is no out-of-the-box mechanism to add new items to your datasource, you will have to do the item-generation yourself anyway.

Alternatively, you can bind both - SelectedItem and Text of your ComboBox - to avoid lookups in case the user has entered a known item. But that part may be less important to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I based this on Mr. Gale's answer. It uses a list of floats instead of strings and checks if the entered value has already been added to the list

```
private float zoomFactor = 2;
public float ZoomFactor
{
     get { return zoomFactor; }
     set
     {
         SetProperty(ref zoomFactor, value);
     }
 public float NewZoom
    {
        get { return zoomFactor; }
        set
        {
            if (!zoomValues.Contains(value))
                zoomValues.Add(value);
            ZoomFactor = value;
        }
    }
    
    private ObservableCollection<float> zoomValues = new ObservableCollection<float>()
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4
    };
    public ObservableCollection<float> ZoomValues { get => zoomValues; }
```

and the XAML:

```
                <ComboBox
                  IsEditable="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ZoomValues}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ZoomFactor}"
                  Text="{Binding NewZoom, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this method, and it works but not always. There is Binding on the SelectedItem and on the Text property and it is uncertain which one fires first. It seems if the Text binding fires first then everything is ok, but if the Selected Item then it changes back the text.