# binding an editable combobox and detect inserted text in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, wcf-binding

I have a `ComboBox` that it looks like this:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding JobList}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Job,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Title"
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    IsEditable="True"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    />
```

and its binding to my `ViewModel` that looks like this one:

```
public class ViewModel {
    // this will fill from a database record for a person
    public Job Job {
        get { return _job; }
        set {
            if(value == _job) return;
            _job = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( () => Job );
        }
    }
    // this will fill from all jobs records in database
    public ObservableCollection<Job> JobList 
    { /* do same as Job to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged */ }
}
```

and the `Job` is:

```
public class Job {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Really, I want to fill the `ComboBox` with job's list. So if the user's specified `Job` was in list, user can select it from list, otherwise, he enter a new `Job.Title` in `ComboBox`, the view model notify on it, and create a new `Job` item and also add it to `JobList`.

Have you any idea? can you help me please?

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? From what you posted everything seems correct. Also, could you post how you set the DataContext of your View?

Comment: Look at @Simon_D suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373239/wpf-editable-combobox)

Comment: The problem is that the `Job` property is of type `Job` and combobox text-input can not detect by viewmodel. If I set the `Job` of type `string` and bind `ComboBox.Text` property, then I can't detect the selected item's `Id`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a string property in the viewModel something like 'SelectedJobName'
2. Bind this property to Combobox.Text
3. Wherever you want to use the entered value (Command, Presenter), check if selected value is not null and selectedJobName property value is not/matching.

Comment: Late but good :D I do the same before. But you are new, so I accept and vote-up your answer. Cheer