# Binding a Combobox to values of a File

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combo box that I type my Database Server names in it. I just want it to remeber what I have typed so far so next time it adds it to a list of items in it so I don't have to type the same Database Server name again each time I run the app.
As for saving the names I have typed in the combox, I am fine with saving them in a file, like a text file, Json, XML, whatever.

I don't know how to do the binding? and when to load the file? Can you help me with an example?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="serverTxt" Height="23"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=ServerNames}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete? or that you're adding new items and want them to be saved? Are you familiar with using `Properties.Settings`?

Comment: @DrewJordan  just loading the items I add from that file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that [came from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280453/3845456), with a little updating and added the storage/retrieval. It should get you started at least. Note that this solution requires a second element on your window (I added a second combobox here) because it triggers on `LostFocus`, otherwise it will update for each character as you type.

Set up your xaml like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="149,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding NewItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Then your main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _selectedItem;

    private ObservableCollection<string> ServerNames;
    private string fileLocation = @"C:\Temp\ServerNames.txt";

    public MainWindow()
    {
       ServerNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
        {
            var list = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation).ToList();
            list.ForEach(ServerNames.Add);
        }
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable Items => ServerNames;

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public string NewItem
    {
        set
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                ServerNames.Add(value);
                SelectedItem = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
        {
            File.Create(fileLocation);
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(fileLocation, ServerNames);
    }
}
```