# Combobox stores previous valid entry if empty

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have an editable combobox, the combobox defaults to 10, if I remove 10 so the combobox is empty and click save the combobox will return 10. How can I store the value so that it would not return the valid entry, return empty or 0 instead.

```
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                  Text="{Binding Model.Number}" ItemsSource="{Binding TList}"  
                  IsEnabled="{Binding EnableTComboBox}">
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: could you tell what save button is doing? It might be doing a rebinding the list in model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Editable ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373239/wpf-editable-combobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a selectedItem to check if it has an item in it from the list. If null then combobox is empty.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedT}"
```