# Creating Replacable Placeholder Text in WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Say I have a combobox, where the contents are going to be some function options that I'd like to be able to fill out with parameters. For instance, the options might be

```
[ComboBox option menu drops down to show the following text options]
Foo(int x)
Bar(int y, int z)
HelloWorld(string q)
```

When any of these options are selected by the user, the combobox will close the options menu (as normal) and show the selected option.  However, I'd like the parameter portion to be a sort of 'pre-highlighted' block of text, which upon clicking gives you focus of that highlight so you can immediately over-write it with your parameter choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373239/wpf-editable-combobox

Comment: I do not believe that this question is a duplicate of that one, Robert Harvey.  Let me know if the question is not explanatory enough.

Comment: Also look at stackoverflow.com/questions/2151410/auto-highlight-text-in-a-textbox-control

Comment: It might not be an exact, precisely-aligned fit to what you're doing, but it still contains a lot of information that is relevant to what you're doing.  If you're expecting a drop-in replacement, Telerik has one.

Comment: Which parameter gets highlighted in the case of `Bar(int y, int z)`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner both.  one for int y, one for int z.  you can click on either of these highlight boxes, and the entire text 'int y' or the entire text 'int z' will get highlighted respectively (as if you were going to overwrite the block of text)

Comment: That almost sounds like tokenizable text, where the text within the token can be edited individually. An interesting idea. Definitely nothing I know of can do this right out of the box.

Comment: That also gave me an idea for how to actually make that work.  When I get some time, I'll play with it over the weekend.  I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: @BradleyUffner anything ever come of the weekend?  I've been thinking about trying to implement this with Custom User Controls / Templating, but perhaps that is the wrong route.

Comment: @IanRay Sorry, I got sick Friday night, and ended up not doing much of anything.  I *do* plan to got around to it eventually, but it might end up being later than you are willing to wait.

Comment: @BradleyUffner absolutely can wait, sorry to hear you got sick

Comment: I've been playing a little bit, and produced [this](https://imgur.com/a/2z5Q0).  It still has a some issues (WPF does *not* want to let you do this easily).  You can check out the current source on [GitHub](https://github.com/BradleyUffner/DynamicComboboxTokens), I plan to work on it a bit more.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've been trying my hand at it too.  The solution I think is going to work (albeit rather Frankensteinian) is to build a UserControl containing a RichTextBox and a Combobox.  The RichTextBox is displayed by default, however when the box is clicked/doubleclicked, its hidden and the Combobox is swapped out, giving you the menu options.  When one is selected, the RichTextBox is displayed again with the selected option.  A parser has tokenized the data between parens, and boxed each with rtf format.  Upon a boxed token being selected, it is swapped out for highlighted plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap'n'cheeesy, and it doesn't dream of handling Bradley's case of multiple parameters: It just selects everything between the parens. But it handles the cases you listed.

In real life you'd want to set up this event with an attached behavior, of course.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (ComboBox)sender;

    var item = cb.SelectedItem as SelectMethodCallItem;

    //  This event is raised when user alters the text, but 
    //  SelectedItem will be null in that case. 
    if (item != null && item.HasSelection)
    {
        var edit = (TextBox)cb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cb);

        Action setsel = () =>
        {
            edit.SelectionStart = item.SelStart;
            edit.SelectionLength = item.SelLEngth;
        };
        //  the BeginInvoke/application idle gimmick is so it happens 
        //  after this event is over with, so the change we make isn't stepped on
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, setsel);
    }
}
```

In real life, you could do something much more clever and robust to identify the replaceable parameter text.

```
public class SelectMethodCallItem
{
    public SelectMethodCallItem(String text)
    {
        Text = text;
        SelStart = text.IndexOf('(');
        SelEnd = text.IndexOf(')');

        if (SelStart > -1 && SelEnd > -1)
        {
            ++SelStart;
            ++SelEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            SelStart = SelEnd = -1;
        }
    }

    public String Text { get; set; }
    public int SelStart { get; private set; }
    public int SelEnd { get; private set; }

    public int SelLEngth => (SelEnd - SelStart) - 1;

    public bool HasSelection => SelStart > -1 && SelEnd > -1;
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox
    IsEditable="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CBItems}"
    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    />
```

Code behind

```
public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new 
        {
            CBItems = new[] {
                new SelectMethodCallItem("sin(float x)"),
                new SelectMethodCallItem("cos(float x)"),
                new SelectMethodCallItem("foobar(string s)"),
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the starter Seed, Ed.  God-Tier stuff.  Gonna see if I can't add some type of 'box' element around the parameters after the function is selected, and do the support for multiple boxes.