# How to add items to ViewModel ObservableCollection property from list control? WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

This is my first MVVM project, I hope can be clear.
Having this in Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryViewModel : MyViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Category> categories;

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }

        set
        {
            categories = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Categories));
        }
    }
}
```

In View (XAML)
The items are bound to a ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCategories"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="250"
          IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                      SelectedValuePath="CategoryId"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

Is there a way to add a new item (Category) to the `ObservableCollection` property when the user writes a new entry on the control?

I've been able to do it by showing up a little `Window` with a `TextBox`, but I'd like to know if is possible to short this process.
I'm not really familiar with WPF, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373239/wpf-editable-combobox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Say you had one collection of Category and that is bound to the itemssource of your combo.
You then bind selecteditem to a property of type Category with a propfull so you have setter where you can put code.
When that setter fires you get a selected Category.
You could then do what you like with it.
One option would be to add it to another observablecollection.

The pattern of acting when you select an item off a list is described here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

In that you would add the chef to another observablecollection in DoSomethingWhenChefChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `TextBoxBase.TextChanged` attached event and for example raise a command of the view model or add the item to the `ObservableCollection` directly, e.g.:

```
private void cboCategories_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    var viewModel = DataContext as CategoryViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        viewModel.Categories.Add(new Category() { Description = cmb.Text });
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCategories"
          IsEditable="True"
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cboCategories_TextChanged" ... />
```

If you want to invoke the attached command using an interaction trigger, you could create your own custom `EventTrigger` as suggested here:

http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.se/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3e9fad4-16ee-4744-8b0e-1ea0abfc5da7/how-to-handle-scrollviewerscrollchanged-event-in-mvvm?forum=wpf