# WPF DataGrid - Implementing Combobox column that is editable and filters list based on text inside

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Please bear with me as I am still new to MVVM and WPF C# (and programming in general). I have read alot and feel overwhelmed and just need some guidance to overcome this issue. I will try to simplify my program into a simple example illustrated below:

A supermarket has the following items available:

1. Apple
2. Peach
3. Mango
4. Banana
5. Toilet paper
6. Iphone
7. Water

I have several customers (customer objects). Each customer object contains a collection of his items. The items object contains the name and quantity. For example:

Customer X has the following items in his cart
Item                      Quantity

1. Apple                        1
2. Banana                       2
3. Peaches                      3

So my simplified application is as follows. I open the application and it has a listview with a list of my current customers. I press on a customer and modify it. This will open a new window. The window contains a datagrid. Column one is the item in his cart (combobox column), column two is a text column with the quantity.

I want to be able to modify the item and quantity. My issue is the combobox column; I want it to be editable and allow me to filter the drop down list based on the current input in that cell. For example if I press it on and I dont enter anything, it will have the full list of available items. if I press "a" it will filter the drop down further for all words starting with an "a". I also want to implement validation so that the combobox column doesnt allow for any duplicates (I will probably be able to figure this out alone).

Here is some code I have implemented quickly for this example (MVVM structure). This code skips the first window and goes straight into the window with the datagrid
**My Models**
*Customer.cs*

```
public class Customer:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public Customer()
    {

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

}
```

*Item.cs*

```
    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private double quantity;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public double Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return quantity;
        }
        set
        {
            quantity = value;
        }
    }


    public Item()
    {
              
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Customer ObjCustomer
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<object> itemslist;
    public ObservableCollection<object> ItemsList
    {
        get { return itemslist; }
        set { itemslist = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ObjCustomer = new Customer();
        ObjCustomer.Items = LoadCustomerItems();
        ItemsList = LoadAvailableItems();
    }
    
    private ObservableCollection<object> LoadAvailableItems()
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> combosAndLoadCasesList = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Apple" });
        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Peach" });
        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Mango" });
        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Banana" });
        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Toilet paper" });
        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Iphone" });
        combosAndLoadCasesList.Add(new Item() { Name = "Water" });

        return combosAndLoadCasesList;
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Item> LoadCustomerItems()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsForCustomer =  new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        ItemsForCustomer.Add(new Item() { Name = "Apple", Quantity = 1 });
        ItemsForCustomer.Add(new Item() { Name = "Banana", Quantity = 2 });
        ItemsForCustomer.Add(new Item() { Name = "Peaches", Quantity = 3 });
        return ItemsForCustomer;
    }
}
```

*My window xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxDemo"
    xmlns:Syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
    xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="374" 
              Margin="37,31,0,64" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              Width="391"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ObjCustomer.Items,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Item"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                                    TextBinding="{Binding BindingGroupName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"
                                Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

I have played around with some WPF frameworks such as Syncfusion. Do you guys recommend these going forward or should I stick with the standard WPF functionality? If there any tips for me going forward please advise!

Comment: My first suggestion is - don't use Combobox inside a data-grid. Infact you are trying to create a items for a customer which you can keep it under a normal grid (for design purpose).

And then add those selected item + quantity to an object and object add it to finally a collection (in your model). That viewmodel object you bind to a DataGrid. This makes simpler for data operations (Adding, Editing and Deleting).

Comment: Second question - "This code skips the first window and goes straight into the window with the datagrid My Models Customer.cs"

Are you saying this is your current one of the issue you are facing?

Comment: If you are looking for editable combo-box then have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280453/1966993

If you have some other question then let us know.

Comment: Generally speaking. Don't allow users to edit directly in a datagrid (or listview).  Use the datagrid to pick what they want to work with then work on that object or a copy of it in a separate panel. Either on top of the datagrid or side by side. On top is often better because you can block the user from exiting that panel until they complete and save valid data or abandon their edit.

Comment: @GK Thanks for your comments. GK 1) The real program I am trying to code is actually a plugin and the original software the plugin will be attached to uses a datagrid to manipulate the object. I undrstand this might not be the best way but I want the plugin to be as close as the software itself. 2) I skip the first window creation because this is a simplified version and is not related to the issue im facing. My only issue is related to the combobox column. 3) I have seen that post but I am not sure how to change the implementation from stand-alone combobox to combobox column in datagrid

Comment: @Andy the current software I am writing the plugin for uses this method unfortunately. You modify the object in a datagrid similar structure or way (I think the interface is in winforms though not WPF). I dont like the idea of select the item I want to modify then pressing a seperate button to do it side by side or in another window. Its just an additional step that can be done right at the datagrid no? Like similar to modify a table in excel

Comment: If you give the users something works like excel, they use it like excel. Validation becomes a nuisance unless your data can be validated as they type into any and all cells.

Comment: @andy I understand but its just for this window that I am looking for this behavior..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SO page with a couple of answers to your filtered/autocomplete combobox question: [Autocomplete combobox for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963022/autocomplete-combobox-for-wpf)

I notice your set properties are all missing the call to `OnPropertyRaised` which would make your bindings not work - especially the quantity one. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification for how that should work.

> I have played around with some WPF frameworks such as Syncfusion. Do you guys recommend these going forward or should I stick with the standard WPF functionality? If there any tips for me going forward please advise!

I personally use [Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/) and absolutely love them, but they also take some time to get used to and learn. Plus they're not cheap.

I also tend to use [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/) for MVVM instead of plain WPF since I get lots of stuff out of the box like navigation, auto linking Views to ViewModels and a global event aggregator for passing around events.

You will probably find that every single person has a different opinion about whether to use these libraries or not. I find they help and make me more productive so I would personally recommend using them.

PS: Just wanted to add that if you use a library like devexpress you will mostly get controls like the dropdown autocomplete already built in like [this one](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ComboBoxEdit)...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Mladen Mihajlovic! I have seen Devexpress but unfortunately they dont have a community version I can use for my "hobby" projects. My projects are not that profitable (if I try to sell them) to justify the high cost of devexpress. Syncfusion allows for community version but I am not sure if its as good. I saw the post you have recommended but this is for a standalone combobox not a comboboxcolumn. I will give it another attempt trying to modify it so that it applies to my comboboxcolumn not sure I will succeed.

Comment: I was just checking devexpress out again. They have free WinUI tools that includes datagrid. Do you think that will be suitable for me for this purpose?

Comment: Personally, I dislike the devexpress controls. Telerik if you can afford it ( maybe they do a free version I dunno ).  Or just use the regular datagrid. A template column if combo box column doesn't suit.

Comment: @andy Both those you mentioned dont have community licenses. Only one I found was syncfusion. I cannot find an implementation of comboboxcolumns that has the filtering I need. The ones I find online are for standalone combo boxes and I am not sure how to take that implementation into a datagrid

Comment: @MElSawy here's some more ideas for the datagrid combo https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e40dd8c-ba61-4248-acd5-1fddb67b4e62/autocomplete-datagridcomboboxcolumn?forum=wpf

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic I have a question regarding modifying data in a datagrid. Do you usually open a "copy" of the object in the datagrid and do your modifications on that then commit these changes to the original object or whats the real "MVVM" way?

Comment: @MElSawy I would say there is no hard and fast rule - it depends on whether you would want to restore the object to pre-editing state. If not then I see no reason why you could not use the object within the list - but I must say I usually like having a cancel/reset button which would mean I would make a clone/copy and work on that rather.